# Stateful widget dispose method not called

Tags: flutter

I have a list if widgets that I swipe off the screen. On swipe, i remove the first widget from the list but i realized the dispose method of that widget is not called therefore the AnimationContoller is still held by flutter and used for the subsequent widgets. Animation for the subsequent widgets are ended by the time they are brought to the front. This makes my app not behave as expected. To test this, I print a string in the initState and dispose method of the widgets. The initState prints but the dispose method does not. Any help please ?

```
class ProfileWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  ProfileWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ProfileWidgetState();
}

class _ProfileWidgetState extends State<ProfileWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("New init");

    _animationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );

    _fadeAnimationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );

    _fadeAnimation = new Tween(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(_fadeAnimationController);

    _fadeAnimationController.forward();

  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Disposing");

    if (_animationController != null) {
      _animationController.dispose();
    }

    if (_fadeAnimationController != null) {
      _fadeAnimationController.dispose();
    }

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a known bug in flutter and the discussion is ongoing: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40940
even if you copy examples from official docs, it will not get called: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets#complete-example
however flutter devs claim that this a desired behavior. Please voice your support in the github issue if you think it should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely do that.